# I changed spring boot app to spring mvc but my log4j2.xml is not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

**I change spring boot to spring MVC**, but **I can't see any log information in my log file but it populates in the console**. Please let me know the changes I need to make in the log4j2.xml file so that log info will be saved to log files.

what is ***monitorinterval=30*** in the below XML file?

**Thank you soo much for the response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${hostName} --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
        </Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>

        <!-- Rolling File Appender -->
        <RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="logs/prism.log"
                     filePattern="logs/prism-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.zip">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.heymath" level="debug"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: How did you configure log4j2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

monitorInterval=30 tells Log4j2 to check every 30 seconds to see if the logging configuration has changed and reconfigure if it has.

I see nothing obviously wrong with your configuration. It should be logging all info, warn, error and fatal messages to the file and console. Debug messages from com.heymath loggers should be going there as well.

I would suggest changing the status="WARN" to status="DEBUG" on the configuration element. If you do not see logs from log4j it means that your configuration file was not found and is not being used. Instead, it is using the default configuration which logs errors to the console.